# I hid VsCode ''previewer'' on Chrome Developer tools and JavaScript code doesn't get returned in the console

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console, google-chrome-devtools

I was doing some JavaScript exercises using Live Preview and I clicked by mistake on an option called ''Hide vs-code...'' right above the ''Clear console'' option, and now if I type any code on Vs Code and try to run it in, it does not get returned into Chrome's console, and I don't know how to make it appear back again.

[image]

I searched online and I tried looking everywhere in the console but I could not find anything.